# Direct VBA to save a copy of a spread sheet in a designated folder in outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have code to take a copy of a select worksheet but am haveing difficulties directing which draft folder in outlook to send the draft email to.  The name of the folder I want to send the draft email to is "Draft NDIC".  Here is the code:

```
Sub Mail_Body_NDIC()
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim OutApp As Object
  Dim OutMail As Object
  With Application
      .EnableEvents = False
      .ScreenUpdating = False
  End With

  Set rng = Nothing
  Set rng = Sheets("NDIC Renewals").UsedRange
  'You can also use a sheet name
  'Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").UsedRange

  Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

  On Error Resume Next
  With OutMail
      .To = "dvandervieren@enerplus.com"
      .CC = ""
      .BCC = ""
      .Subject = "NDIC Renewals for the Next 90 Days"
      .Body = ""
      .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
      .Save   'or use .Display
  End With
  On Error GoTo 0

  With Application
      .EnableEvents = True
      .ScreenUpdating = True
  End With

  Set OutMail = Nothing
  Set OutApp = Nothing
 End Sub
```

Comment: I am hesitant to put this an answer since a simple google search will return the answer quit [easily](http://blog.saieva.com/2010/03/27/move-messages-to-folders-with-outlook-vba/)... You need to use the `.Move` method, with the `olDestFolder` as the argument. The link I referenced will show you exactly how to do it.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman To my mind, you may as well post an answer because it does not seem to be available on SO. :)

Answer (score 0):

"You need to use the .Move method, with the olDestFolder as the argument." David Van der Vieren

http://blog.saieva.com/2010/03/27/move-messages-to-folders-with-outlook-vba/